# JasperReports: File Name incorrect while exporting report to Excel

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am trying to export report in excel (xls) format and giving the option download the file from the browser with the help of open / save dialog box.

When the File download box pops up, the File Name is not coming correctly. The File Name comes as URL

Below is my code:

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReportMCQ, params, datasource);

JRXlsExporter jasperXlsExportMgr = new JRXlsExporter();

ByteArrayOutputStream xlsReport = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
jasperXlsExportMgr.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
jasperXlsExportMgr.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.TRUE);
jasperXlsExportMgr.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, java.lang.Boolean.FALSE);
jasperXlsExportMgr.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, java.lang.Boolean.FALSE);
jasperXlsExportMgr.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, java.lang.Boolean.TRUE);
jasperXlsExportMgr.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, java.lang.Boolean.TRUE);
jasperXlsExportMgr.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_COLLAPSE_ROW_SPAN, java.lang.Boolean.TRUE);
jasperXlsExportMgr.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_CELL_BORDER, java.lang.Boolean.FALSE);
jasperXlsExportMgr.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.CREATE_CUSTOM_PALETTE, java.lang.Boolean.TRUE);
jasperXlsExportMgr.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, xlsReport);
jasperXlsExportMgr.exportReport();
bytes = xlsReport.toByteArray();
getResponse().setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"report.xls\"");
getResponse().setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
getResponse().setContentLength(bytes.length);
if (bytes.length > 0) {
    servletOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    servletOutputStream.flush();
    servletOutputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change a JasperReport's actual name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738253/how-can-i-change-a-jasperreports-actual-name) & [JasperReports PdfServlet to save report in PDF - how can I set the filename for the browser to prompt the user?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12095833/876298)

Answer (score 1):

Try this parameter:

jasperXlsExportMgr.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "MyFile");

From the Jasper Doc:

static JRExporterParameter OUTPUT_FILE_NAME: The file name of the exported report.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS CODE :

```
String dir = "C:/myproject/";
Connection kns = BukaKoneksi(url);   
HashMap hm = new HashMap(); 
String name = dir+"file/_.xls"";
String nfl = dir+"file/__.xls"; 
String fjas = "a.jasper";   
String nname = "a.xls";

//jasper
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(dir+"jasper/"+fjas, hm, kns);
JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
ByteArrayOutputStream xlsReport = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, xlsReport);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE, fname);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, nfl);
exporter.exportReport();    

//download file
byte bytes[] = xlsReport.toByteArray(); 
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+nname); 
response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
xlsReport.close();
OutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();
ouputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
ouputStream.flush();
ouputStream.close();
```